# OLEDB IMultipleResults->getResult is not returning rowset

Tags: oledb

I have a stored procedure in the sql server database, and it contains a select statement so it should be returned as a resulset when invoking the stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure SqlTxFunctionTesting (
                                  @inparam decimal(15,3),
                                  @outparam decimal(15,3) output,
                                  @inoutparam decimal(15,3) output)
                                  AS 
                                  BEGIN 
                                  set @outparam = @inparam * 2;
                                  set @inoutparam = @inoutparam * 4;
                                  select * from resultsetdata;
                                  return @inparam * 8;
                                  END
```

I'm executing the stored procedure using

```
m_pICommandText->Execute(NULL, IID_IMultipleResults, 
                                    &params, &nRowsAffected, (IUnknown **)&m_IMultipleResultSets)))
```

and trying to fetch the resultset using

```
HRESULT getResultSetRetCode = m_IMultipleResultSets->GetResult(NULL, 0, IID_IRowset, &
                nRowsAffected, (IUnknown **)&m_pIRowset);
```

The first call returns S_OK and m_pIRowset is NULL and the second call returns DB_S_NORESULT. 
Why is it not returning the resultset for the select statement? Please help before I shoot myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if you asked the [same question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3072fc0e-20a8-472a-a25b-9ce2f08b05b9/oledb-imultipleresultsgetresult-is-not-returning-rowset) here also but seems very similar:-

> I discovered this while trying to create the standalone test program.
>   I had created my stored procedure on the database that I thought was
>   the default database for the user I was connecting as. The default
>   database turned out to be set to something else, and that database
>   also had a stored procedure with the same name, but without having any
>   select statement (resultset). So I had wrongly thought that the stored
>   procedure was executing select statement but it was not available to
>   the OLEDB program.

So in short the problem could be at your end itself!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server stored procedures can have integer return codes and output parameters. The return codes and output parameters are sent in the last packet from the server and are therefore not available to the application until the row-set is completely released.

If the command returns multiple results, output parameter data is available when IMultipleResults::GetResult returns **DB_S_NORESULT** (*End of results reached*) or the IMultipleResults interface is completely released, whichever occurs first.